# Mysql Trigger Delete statment give syntax error. But not when it run alone

Tags: mysql, triggers

I'm using 000webhost for my school project. It don't have event feature in free version. So I'm using Trigger to delete tuples if it expired. But that gives

> "#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '' at line 4".

Here's my Trigger SQL

```
CREATE TRIGGER notification_delete
AFTER DELETE ON notification
FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN
    DELETE
    FROM notification
    WHERE (DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), date_created) > 2);
END
```

I checked DELETE Statement it working fine

```
DELETE
FROM notification
WHERE (DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), date_created) > 2);
```

Here's my table

```
CREATE TABLE notification (
    id INT (11) NOT NULL
    ,user_id INT (11) NOT NULL
    ,message VARCHAR(1023) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL
    ,priority SET (
        '1'
        ,'2'
        ,'3'
        ,'4'
        ,'5'
        ) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL
    ,date_created DATE NOT NULL
    ,breakdown_user_id INT (11) DEFAULT NULL
    ,appointment_id INT (11) DEFAULT NULL
    ,order_id INT (11) DEFAULT NULL
    ) ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8 COLLATE = utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/stored-programs-defining.html If you use the mysql client program to define a stored program containing semicolon characters, a problem arises. By default, mysql itself recognizes the semicolon as a statement delimiter, so you must redefine the delimiter temporarily to cause mysql to pass the entire stored program definition to the server.

Comment: Won't work even if you clear syntax error you will get an execution error because you are not allowed to action the table which called the trigger.

Comment: It would cause some cascading effects. You should turn these 2 comments into an answer @P.Salmon

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the `;` - you need to have another delimiter in effect or the parser will interpret that semicolon as the end of the query.

```
DELIMITER |

CREATE TRIGGER notification_delete AFTER DELETE on notification
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM notification WHERE (DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), date_created)>2);
END

DELIMITER ;
```

You may have other difficulties after you fix that, however, as there are restrictions on modifying tables that were used in the query that triggers the action. You may need to get creative about which database action triggers this. Since it's just a general cleanup that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Thanks. I don't know why you were previously downvoted but this was the answer for me. I needed to set a different delimiter so the `END IF` within the trigger and the `END` to end the trigger didn't have the same delimiters.